# Resolving TypeError in Python code

Tags: python, pandas

I'm basically running some code as follows. Basically I'm just retrieving pairs of stocks (laid out as Row 1-Stock 1,2, Row 2-Stock 1,2 and   so on, where Stock 1 and 2 are different in each row) from a CSV File. I then take in data from Yahoo associated with these "Pairs" of Stocks. I calculate the returns of the stocks and basically check if the distance (difference in returns) between a pair of stocks breaches some threshold and if so I return 1. However, I'm getting the following error which I am unable to resolve:

```
PricePort(tickers)
     27     for ticker in tickers:
     28         #print ticker
---> 29         x = pd.read_csv('http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ttt'.replace('ttt',ticker),usecols=[0,6],index_col=0)
     30         x.columns=[ticker]
     31         final=pd.merge(final,x,left_index=True,right_index=True)

TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

The code is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import csv
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
import numpy as np

#Retrieves pairs of stocks (laid out as Row 1-Stock 1,2, Row 2-Stock 1,2 and   so on, where Stock 1 and 2 are different in each row) from CSV File
def Dataretriever():
        Pairs = []
        f1=open('C:\Users\Pythoncode\Pairs.csv') #Enter the location of the file
        csvdata= csv.reader(f1)
        for row in csvdata:          #reading tickers from the csv file
            Pairs.append(row)
        return Pairs

tickers = Dataretriever() #Obtaining the data

#Taking in data from Yahoo associated with these "Pairs" of Stocks
def PricePort(tickers):
    """
        Returns historical adjusted prices of a portfolio of stocks.
        tickers=pairs
    """
    final=pd.read_csv('http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GSPC',usecols=[0,6],index_col=0)
    final.columns=['^GSPC']
    for ticker in tickers:
        #print ticker
        x = pd.read_csv('http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ttt'.replace('ttt',ticker),usecols=[0,6],index_col=0)
        x.columns=[ticker]
        final=pd.merge(final,x,left_index=True,right_index=True)
    return final   

#Calculating returns of the stocks
def Returns(tickers):
    l = []
    begdate=(2014,1,1)
    enddate=(2014,6,1)    
    p = PricePort(tickers)
    ret = (p.close[1:] - p.close[:-1])/p.close[1:]
    l.append(ret)
    return l

#Basically a class to see if the distance (difference in returns) between a 
#pair of stocks breaches some threshold
class ThresholdClass():    
    #constructor
    def __init__(self, Pairs):
        self.Pairs = Pairs

    #Calculating the distance (difference in returns) between a pair of stocks
    def Distancefunc(self, tickers):
        k = 0
        l = Returns(tickers)
        summation=[[0 for x in range (k)]for x in range (k)]      #2d matrix for the squared distance
        for i in range (k):
            for j in range (i+1,k):     # it will be a upper triangular matrix
                for p in range (len(self.PricePort(tickers))-1):
                    summation[i][j]= summation[i][j] + (l[i][p] - l[j][p])**2       #calculating distance

        for i in range (k):     #setting the lower half of the matrix 1 (if we see 1 in the answer we will set a higher limit but typically the distance squared is less than 1)
            for j in range (i+1):
                sum[i][j]=1
            return sum

    #This function is used in determining the threshold distance
    def MeanofPairs(self, tickers):
        sum = self.Distancefunc(tickers)
        mean = np.mean(sum)
        return mean

    #This function is used in determining the threshold distance
    def StandardDeviation(self, tickers):
        sum = self.Distancefunc(tickers)
        standard_dev = np.std(sum)
        return standard_dev 


    def ThresholdandnewsChecker(self, tickers):
        threshold = self.MeanofPairs(tickers) + 2*self.StandardDeviation(tickers)
        if (self.Distancefunc(tickers) > threshold):
            return 1 

Threshold_Class  = ThresholdClass(tickers)   
Threshold_Class.ThresholdandnewsChecker(tickers,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is `Dataretriever()` returns a list, not a string. When you iterate over `tickers()`, the name `ticker` is bound to a list.

The `str.replace` method expects both arguments to be strings. The following code raises the error because the second argument is a list:

```
'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ttt'.replace('ttt', ticker)
```

The subsequent line `x.columns = [ticker]` will cause similar problems. Here, `ticker` needs to be a hashable object (like a string or integer), but lists are not hashable.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code as follows, yet I still have the same issue:       `tickersasstrings = map(str, tickers)

       def PricePort(tickersasstrings):
    final=pd.read_csv('http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GSPC',usecols=[0,6],index_col=0)
    final.columns=['^GSPC']
    for ticker in tickersasstrings:
        #print ticker
        x = pd.read_csv('http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ttt'.replace('ttt',ticker),usecols=[0,6],index_col=0)
        x.columns=[ticker]
        final=pd.merge(final,x,left_index=True,right_index=True)
    return final`

Comment: I'd guess it's because of the `x.columns=[ticker]` bit. `x.columns` needs to assigned to a list strings or numbers (hashable) not a list of lists (unhashable).

Comment: Thanks Again. I tried changing it to `x.columns = ticker` as it would then just be assigned a list of strings, however this does not appear to resolve the issue. Could there be another problem?

Comment: Nothing jumps out - what's the new error message you're getting?

Comment: Its the same one as before.

Comment: Just checking: should the URL be, for example, `http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM` (note the "i" in "ichart").

Comment: The URL without the "i" usually works fine, so I think that part might be okay.